# How to take action on the current line of one file based on the next line in a different file

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to learn file handling in Python. I need to create a new file with the below changes.
I have the following Input file:-

Input File:-

```
Hello World!!!    
foo bar qss     
> foot    
> grass     
> flower    
> leaf    
foo1 bar1 qss1    
> dragon    
> quiz    
foo2 bar2 qsq1    
foo3 bar3 qsa2
```

My Output file should be:-

```
Hello World!!!    
foo bar qss foot grass flower leaf
foo1 bar1 qss1 dragon quiz
foo2 bar2 qsq1
foo3 bar3 qsa2
```

So, If there is '>' in next line, it should copy the contents to the current line.

I tried to use next() but it takes the file pointer to the next line.

```
#f1 is read file pointer
#f2 is write file pointer

for myline in f1:
  if(next(f1) != '>'):
    f2.write("myline[1]+" "+myline[2]+" "+myline[3]+"  "+next(f1)[3])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looking forward, look *backward*: add a line break to the previous line only if the next line does not start with "> ".

```
with open("f.txt") as f1, open("g.txt", "w") as f2:
    for myline in f1:
        myline = myline.strip() # Remove the line break
        if myline.startswith("> "):
            f2.write(myline[1:])
        else:
            f2.write("\n" + myline)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
with open(r"input.txt") as input:
    lines = input.readlines()
new_lines = (''.join(lines).replace('\n> ', ''))
with open(r"output.txt", 'w') as output:
    output.writelines(new_lines)
```

input:

```
Hello World!!!    
foo bar qss     
> foot    
> grass     
> flower    
> leaf    
foo1 bar1 qss1    
> dragon    
> quiz    
foo2 bar2 qsq1    
foo3 bar3 qsa2
```

output:

```
Hello World!!!    
foo bar qss     foot    grass     flower    leaf    
foo1 bar1 qss1    dragon    quiz    
foo2 bar2 qsq1    
foo3 bar3 qsa2
```

Hope it helped

Comment: The lines starting with '>' are not to be removed entirely, they need to be appended to the previous line as well.

Comment: fixed according to your comment